# How can i force my logo to be smaller and on top left on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, styling

I just positioned the logo on top of my Header-Image, on Desktop it's perfect but if i change to mobile it's covering the menu Floating on the right side.

I want to Keep it to stay in the left corner, but smaller.

My php looks like this:

```
<a href="/"> <id="logo"><img class="img-logo" src="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/images/logo.png" width="180" alt="logo"></a>

   <img class="headerpic" src="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/images/headspacer.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="infobox"><div class="inner">    
    </div>
```

and the Styling is currently like this:

```
.img-logo{
position:absolute;
top: 120px;
left: 250px;

}

.header img.headerpic  { 
    max-width:100%; 
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: -1500;
}
```

What additional Styling or changes do i Need to make that the logo get's a bit smaller and moves to the top left on mobiles?
[The Actual reaction to the styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWTSJ.jpg)

Comment: Do you have an image that you can show what it looks like right now?

Comment: @mmenschig added an image now. Hope it helps. Do you need more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the viewport http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

This will basically make your app react based on the size of the screen.

One tip to make this behavior tested will be using the Google Chrome console as it allows you to change the viewport size based on device type.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 829px) {

 /* Your css for smaller screen here */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 830px) {
/*Your css for bigger screen here*/
}
```

Comment: I haven't yet sorry didn't answer correctly. I'm not skilled enough to do this could you give me a bit help?